# PHP don't add blank values to a new array

Tags: php

I'm running an XPath request and trying to build an array but since it's an XPath request some values contain just `&nbsp;` or just one space.

I have done some research but none of the solutions I found helped.

```
foreach ($dataArray as $value) {
    if (strpos($value, 'string A') !== false ||
        strpos($value, 'string B — ') !== false ||
        trim($value[1]) == ' ' ||
        strlen($value) < 2 ||
        ctype_space($value)) {
        continue;
    } else {
        $dataArray2[] = $value;
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($dataArray2);
echo '</pre>';
```

Result:

```
[0] => string C
[1] => string C
[2] => string C
[3] =>   // This is created even though it should not get into the array.
[4] => string C
[5] => string C
[6] => string C
[7] => string C
[8] => string C
[9] => string C
[10] => string C
```

EDIT:

Tried `empty(trim($value[1])` and it didn't work so I decided to check what `$value[1]` really is and used `var_dump($value[1]);`. 
Result:
`string(1) "�"`
I'm not sure if it should be this way but `�` turned an alert for me.

Comment: Try changing `trim($value[1]) == ' ' ` to `empty(trim($value[1]))`. And after `trim` it's not possible for result to be one space.

Comment: As an alternative to creating a new array have a look at `array_filter()` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

Comment: Try `empty(trim($value))`, `$value[1]` will be the second character of the string in `$value`

Comment: maybe add something like `if($value) {$dataArray2[] = $value;}` in the else statement. That should do the trick. But it does not explain why the empty element is created...

Comment: Although you don't have the XPath in the code, you could look into the `normalize-space()` function.

Comment: @JRsz's suggestion led me to the solution. @NigelRen - I've just noticed that I didn't do `normalize-space()`, there is a lot going on there though, so maybe I didn't add it for a reason, ill check into that as well. Thanks, everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fixed** by adding `if (strlen($value) > 2)` to my else statement so this final code now looks like this:

```
foreach ($dataArray as $value) {
    if (strpos($value, 'string A') !== false ||
        strpos($value, 'string B — ') !== false ||
        trim($value[1]) == ' ' ||
        strlen($value) < 2 ||
        ctype_space($value)) {
        continue;
    } elseif (strlen($value) > 2) {
        $dataArray2[] = $value;
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($dataArray2);
echo '</pre>';
```

As suggested in the comments by @JRsz.

Also, I've changed `print_r` to `var_dump` just to check how many spaces the blank values have. It was a good move because it turned out that the string length is `2`, and this is how I came up with `> 2`.

Not sure if this is the best way to do that but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try to catch $value[1] by using the empty() function

Answer (score 0):

May be this solution can help you:

```
foreach ($dataArray as $value) {
    $trimmed = trim($value);
    if (!empty($trimmed)) {
        $dataArray2[] = $value;
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($dataArray2);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: This didn't work, I've posted an answer with what worked for me. Thanks for taking the time to answer though.